# Is there a way to speed up cassandra nodeltool repair ?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've 10 nodes of Cassandra Cluster and currently installed version is 3.0.13.
How I launched  : nodetool repair -j 4 -pr

Would like to know if there are some configuration options to speed up this process, I still see "Anticompaction after repair" is in progress when i check for compactionstats.

Answer (score 2):

The current state of the art way of doing repairs are subrange repairs running all the time. See http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/12/14/should-you-use-incremental-repair.html for some explanations:

> While the idea behind incremental repair is brilliant, the implementation still has flaws that can cause severe damage to a production cluster, especially when using LCS and DTCS. The improvements and fixes planned for 4.0 will need to be thoroughly tested to prove they fixed incremental repair and allow it to be safely used as a daily routine.

That beeing said (or quoted), have a look at http://cassandra-reaper.io/ - a simple and easy tool managing your repairs.